# Doctrine Entity returning NULL in all attributes (except ID) (DOCTRINE2 + ZF2)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I'm doing a query using a repository.
The return comes only with the correct ID, the rest of the attributes are NULL but in the database all are filled in correctly. What is going on?

**Return:**

```
object(UserBundle\Entity\User)#428 (15) { ["id":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> int(1) ["name":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["company":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["cpf":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["cnpj":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["email":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["password":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["hash":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["plan":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["released":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["is_admin":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["created_at":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["updated_at":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["original_password":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> NULL ["hydrator":"Base\Entity\AbstractEntity":private]=> NULL }
```

**My Entity (User):**

http://pastebin.com/SBnPYY63

**My Repository (User):**

http://pastebin.com/56rwhtmZ

**My 'query':**

```
$repository = $this->em->getRepository('UserBundle\Entity\User');
        $user = $repository->findByEmailAndPassword('email@email.com', 'password');
```

My BD configuration file (doctrine_orm.local.php):

```
<?php

return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'metadata_cache' => 'array',
                'query_cache' => 'array',
                'result_cache' => 'array',
                'hydration_cache' => 'array',
                'generate_proxies' => true,
                'proxy_dir' => 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
                'proxy_namespace' => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
            )
        ),
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => 'my-project',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET SESSION sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'",
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Did try what you get when using the the getters (for example `$name = $user->getName();`)? If your user entity isn't initialized you will still have a proxy and you won't get any properties when dumping the object.